# Can a Flex AIR app on Android start up as a service on boot?

Tags: android, apache-flex, service, air

I understand you can create a service in Android and start it up on boot, which can then be used to get location updates, communicate with a server, etc.

However what I wanted to find out is if this possible to do in AIR. AIR runs on Android, but can it be set a 'service' and start up on boot (`sitting in the background`)?

Thank you!

Comment: In light of Adnan's answer, I decided to search an alternate route and coming up with the following (not sure if it's valid or not). Will try it out this weekend and see if it has any merit:   

I am hoping to extend the AIR app using Java, creating a service for it that sits in the background, communicates and only launches the swf (AIR) when it needs to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application will be running inside the AIR runtime which itself is not a service. So the short answer is unfortunately no.

Also the AIR runtime is a whopping `16MB`, so you (and more so your users) are better if you write a native Android Service.

Comment: Thanks, wish there was a way around it. Appreciate the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible.
Place this code inside application.xml

```
       <application>
                <activity>
                    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                    </intent-filter>
                </activity>
                <receiver android:enabled="true" android:name="packeg.and.Class" 
                          android:exported="true" 
                          android:permission="android.permission.WHAT_YOU_NEED" 
                          > 
                    <intent-filter android:priority="999" > 
                        <action android:name="android.provider.some.SERVICE" />
                    </intent-filter> 
                </receiver>
                <activity android:name="your.package.MainActivity">
     </activity>
 </application>
```

Of course you first need to write Java code and later make ANE file.